# Haskell streaming download

Tags: haskell, conduit

The two resources I found that suggested recipes for streaming downloads using popular Haskell libraries were:

- https://haskell-lang.org/library/http-client#Streaming
- http://www.alfredodinapoli.com/posts/2013-07-20-slick-http-download-in-haskell.html

How would I modify the code in the former to (a) save to file, and (b) print only a (take 5) of the byte response, rather than the whole response to stdout?

My attempt at (b) is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --install-ghc --resolver lts-5.13 runghc
   --package http-conduit
 -}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import qualified Data.ByteString        as S
import qualified Data.Conduit.List      as CL
import           Network.HTTP.Simple
import           System.IO              (stdout)

main :: IO ()
main = httpSink "http://httpbin.org/get" $ \response -> do
    liftIO $ putStrLn
           $ "The status code was: "
          ++ show (getResponseStatusCode response)

    CL.mapM_ (take 5) (S.hPut stdout)
```

Which fails to map the (take 5), and suggests to me among other things I still don't understand how mapping over monads works, or liftIO.

Also, this resource:

http://haskelliseasy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#note-on-streaming

...gave me a warning, "I know what I'm doing and I'd like more fine-grained control over resources, such as streaming" that this not easily or generally supported.

Other places I looked:

- [Downloading large files from the Internet in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718873/downloading-large-files-from-the-internet-in-haskell)
- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq
- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-http

If there's anything in the Haskellverse that makes this easier, more like Python's requests:

```
response = requests.get(URL, stream=True)
for i,chunk in enumerate(response.iter_content(BLOCK)):
  f.write(chunk)
```

I'd appreciate the tip there, too, or pointers towards the 2016 state of the art.

Comment: Do you actually need to stream this? (So are you getting a sufficiently large amount of data at once that having it all in memory is unacceptable?)

Comment: Yes please, I am.

Comment: I probably should have chosen a more sensible number of bytes, like some 2^n...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`httpSource`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2016-11-26/http-conduit-2.2.3/Network-HTTP-Simple.html#v:httpSource) from the latest version of `http-conduit`. It behaves pretty much exactly like Python's requests: you get back a stream of chunks.

> save to file

This is easy, just redirect the source straight into a file sink.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --install-ghc --resolver nightly-2016-11-26 runghc --package http-conduit -}

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Simple (httpSource, getResponseBody)
import Conduit

main = runConduitRes $ httpSource "http://httpbin.org/get" getResponseBody
                    .| sinkFile "data_file"
```

> print only a (take 5) of the byte response

Once we have the source, we take the first 5 bytes with `takeCE 5` and then print these via `printC`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --install-ghc --resolver nightly-2016-11-26 runghc --package http-conduit -}

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Simple (httpSource, getResponseBody)
import Data.ByteString (unpack)
import Conduit

main = runConduitRes $ httpSource "http://httpbin.org/get" getResponseBody
                    .| takeCE 5
                    .| printC
```

> save to file *and* print only a (take 5) of the byte response

To do this, you want [`zipSinks`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.8/docs/Data-Conduit-Internal.html#v:zipSinks) or, for more general cases that involve zipping multiple sinks [`ZipSink`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.5/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:ZipSink):

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --install-ghc --resolver nightly-2016-11-26 runghc --package http-conduit -}

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Simple (httpSource, getResponseBody)
import Data.ByteString (unpack)
import Data.Conduit.Internal (zipSinks)
import Conduit

main = runConduitRes $ httpSource "http://httpbin.org/get" getResponseBody
                    .| zipSinks (takeCE 5 .| printC)
                                (sinkFile "data_file")
```

Comment: Actually, takeCE will take exactly give elements of the stream, aka five bytes.

Comment: Sorry, still learning conduit and this whole way of thinking: What modification to kind of tee this to /both/ stream the takeC5 to stdout and also sink to file?

Comment: @Mittenchops Updated the answer. `ZipSource`,  `ZipSink`, and `ZipConduit` are your friends for forking/joining.

Comment: Thanks, @Alec.  I was a little confused in how to get the resolver set up, but I got this running and the forking of multiple sinks makes a lot of sense to me, more than the liftIO and mapM_ in my original example.  This is very helpful!

Comment: The type signature on main here is: main :: IO ((), ()) ?

Comment: @Mittenchops Yeah - I left it as that because it looked nicer (and technically `main` can have `IO a`). If you want to force `main :: IO ()`, just add `() <$` right after the `main = ` and add parens around the whole `runConduitRes ... "data_file")` body.